# Apple Push Notification not working with ad-hoc build

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, adhoc, testflight

In development mode I can send push notification to devices, instead I can't in production, my setup is:

- .pem file that is the combination of aps_production.cer of provisioning portal and the private key of my ad-hoc certificate
- apple server apn: 'gateway.push.apple.com' with 2196 port
- I have a rails server that saves tokens from devices and then sends notification to apple with those device tokens and the previous .file for opening connection
- ad-hoc build applications have (it's rubymotion):
  entitlements['aps-environment'] = 'production'
  entitlements['get-task-allow'] = false
- application when it starts, sends correctly the token to my application server
- I just checked that the token is different from development mode

The problem is that my rails application sends notifications and didn't receive any errors, but nothing arrived on devices.

I'm using testflight for distribute ad-hoc version of my application, but I don't known any problem using testlight and APNS.

What can be?

---

**EDIT** I resolved: the port was wrong, 2195 instead of 2196...

Answer (score 1):

APNs have a separate SSL certificate for production and for development.

You are probably using your development certificate with the production build.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm using the right certificate because I setup inside my rails application, a multi-certificate environment, so the certificate is uploaded from an administration panel (with the relative passphrase).

Comment: Daniele did you find any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @wod he resolved it. See EDIT in his question -> "the port was wrong, 2195 instead of 2196". Actually not only the port, but the url is changed too between production and development (sandbox).