# iOS App Won't start on Testflight Ad Hoc Distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm developing an application that works perfectly well on my phone when I run it through Xcode. But when I distribute a beta through TestFlight, none of the users can run it - **NOTE**: They can install the app on their phones without any problem. The application just closes before it launches and there are no crash logs on TestFlight.

I can connect any of my testers' phones to my computer and run the app on them (using Xcode) just fine. I thought maybe this is a problem with provisioning profiles, but on my phone, I can delete the relevant profile from Settings app then install the app from the TestFlight link, and it still runs fine.

From things I've read on Stack Overflow, this must be because of some difference in "Release" and "debug" settings of the app, but I'm totally lost as to how to debug it. I can't run the app in release mode while it's connected to Xcode, and I can't debug when it's not connected to Xcode.

Any suggestions?

**Update - Resolved**

I did end up "solving" this problem. SO user Cliff Ribaudo had the same problem (apparently he was the only other person) and he posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262733/ios-app-with-static-lib-crashes-only-on-launch-of-archive-build-loaded-ad-hoc-c) and finally found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300800/ios-app-with-static-lib-always-crashes-on-launch-of-ad-hoc-archive-build-cant-r/10302012#10302012). The solution turned out to be setting two linker flags: `STRIP LINKED PRODUCT = NO` & `STRIP STYLE = DEBUGGING SYMBOLS`. I have no idea why this fixed it, and I don't know why it was broken in the first place. But we haven't had this crash since I made these changes.

Comment: Are you sure they can install the app on their phones? If you have a problem with the permissions, testflight downloads the app but cannot install it.

Comment: Yes, they can definitely install the app, but it won't launch.

Comment: You need to get a crash report from an affected user and symbolicate that one with Xcode. This answer shows how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242780/ipad-how-to-get-crash-report/15962089#15962089

Comment: There are no crash logs on TestFlight, which means the app never finishes launching.

Comment: Since the app doesn't even launch, of course you won't find crash logs there. You need to get them directly from the device. The link I provided explains how to do that.

Comment: Finally got a hold of a tester's device. Nothing in the logs. I tried making the app crash, still nothing in logs. The app just wont' launch. No crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Kerni I was able to debug the issue by tracking down the crash report via 
[iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1465) 
. I Selected the Devices I was debugging and opened the Console Tab on the iPhone Configuration Utility hitting clear and check it out. I Saved the log after getting the app to crash again and found that I had been using In-App Audio when I didn't add it to the App ID when I was creating my provisioning profile. This was the only issue. After I went threw all of the steps again the IPA Uploaded just fine. The app installed like one would imagine!

To Put it short :

1. Debugged with iPhone Configuration Utility (issue was In-App Audio wasn't selected on the App ID Generation)
2. Generated a New App ID and Provisioning Profile
3. Created and uploaded a new IPA.

<<<< Console Debugging here >>>>:
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1305502-my-apps-are-failing-to-install-what-do-i-do-

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem and I figured it out. Please see my answer here.

[testflight application closes on start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899867/testflight-application-closes-on-start/24542359#24542359)

Comment: It's interesting that OCMock was the cause for you. For me, the crash logs would say something cryptic about `XCTest.framework` not being found (it wasn't supposed to be found... it's not included in ad-hoc builds), but there would be no stack trace, which makes me think application code never executed. In any case, I updated the post to mention how I solved it.